# Why the plural "sont" is used in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, attributs

The following is an excerpt from *Le Horla* by Guy de Maupassant:

> Le docteur Marrande, le plus illustre et le plus éminent des aliénistes,
>   avait prié trois de ses confrères et quatre savants, s'occupant de sciences
>   naturelles, de venir passer une heure chez lui, dans la maison de santé qu'il
>   dirigeait, pour leur montrer un des ses malades.
>
> Aussitôt que ses amis furent réunis, il leur dit: «Je vais vous parler
>   du cas le plus bizarre et le plus inquiétant que j'aie jamais rencontré.
>   D'ailleurs, je n'ai rien à vous dire de mon client. Il parlera lui-même.»
>   Le docteur alors sonna. Un domestique fit entrer un homme. Il était très
>   maigre comme ***le sont certains fous rongés par une pensée malade***.

In the last sentence, why is the plural "sont" is used here? What does "le" refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plural "sont" is used because its subject is the rest of the sentence (there is an inversion). Since the rest of the sentence is plural (*certains fous...*), the verb needs to be plural.

The "le" refers to the state of being very thin (*très maigre*).

Basically, the author is trying to define exactly how thin the patient is by comparing him to the state that these "fous" would be in. A very basic way to phrase it would have been:

> Il était très maigre comme certains fous rongés par une pensée malade sont très maigres.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you saying that in an "inversion", one must use plural of a verb instead of singular?

Comment: Or is it because "certains" is plural?

Comment: @Jack It's because "certains" is plural. I mention the inversion because it puts the subject after the verb, so it can get confusing what it's agreeing with.

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence: *Il était très maigre **comme le sont certains fous rongés** par une pensée malade*, there is a literary inversion.

Instead of writing: *comme certains fous le sont*, the writer puts the verb first so he can ADD right after the noun *fous*,  *rongés par une pensée malade*. Had the writer not done this, he would have had to rework the entire sentence.